# "Years of experience that keeps us safe." vs "Years of experience that keep us safe."

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, relative-clauses, subjects

If you've ever seen Mythbusters, you know that all episodes contain at least one safety disclaimer. Having recently rewatched several episodes, I've noticed that some disclaimers have Adam saying, "Don't try this at home. We've got years of experience that keeps us safe."

That sounded a little funny to me, and I'm wondering whether that's grammatically correct. Shouldn't it be "years of experience that *keep* us safe"? Technically, it makes sense that it's the singular 'experience' that keeps the Mythbusters safe, but shouldn't the verb 'keep' be referring to the years of experience as a whole? I mean, it's the fact that they've got *years*, and not, say, *minutes*, that are keeping them safe. Right? Or is the sentence perfectly fine?

---

*Update:* I think part of the issue is the word 'experience' itself, which is singular regardless of how much there is of it. Words that come in discrete units (such as, say, 'blocks') are made plural when they're modified by multiple units ('5 blocks') — experience, however, remains singular. 'Much experience', 'experience', and 'no experience' are all singular.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can categorically identify either version as "incorrect".

As OP says, superficially *"We've got years of experience that keep us safe"* seems correct, since the subject of the verb *keep* is the plural noun phrase *years of experience*.

But I personally have no problem parsing it as ***experience*** that **keeps** us safe. The fact that this experience is qualified by *years of* seems to me no different to if it had been qualified by *plenty of*, or *a great deal of*. It's the singular *experience*, not the plural *years*, that helps.

In short, both seem "defensible" to me, but I find the singular verb form flows better.

Comment: I agree with you that both are defensible, but I think that _plenty of_ and _a great deal of_ aren't great substitutes for _years of_, since years are units, and not just modifiers. 'Plenty of experience' is certainly followed by 'keeps', but it's harder (in my mind) to justify the same statement with 'years'.

Comment: On the other hand, I realized that 'experience' is always singular, so it seems like there's no real right answer...

Comment: @Itai Ferber: Well you can't have it both ways. Either you find both acceptable or you don't. I think what you mean is your own "instinctive inner grammarian" agrees with me and the Mythbusters writer that singular sounds "better", but you can't justify it on logical/pedantic grounds. Language is sometimes just like that.

Comment: People say “Ten years is gonna trump two years” or “Three weeks is long enough to wait.”  Just because those subjects are formally plural doesn’t mean they can’t be construed to be singular concepts.