# Is it "5–6 weeks are a lot of time" or "5–6 weeks is a lot of time"?

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, copular-verbs, be

I was just copyediting [somebody's answer on another SE site](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/7048/140) and my native English speaker Sprachgefühl told me I had to correct the grammar of one sentence:

> ... 5–6 weeks **are** a lot of time ...

by changing the ***are*** to ***is***. But as I was doing so I started wondering why is it that in this case it seems that I have to make the verb *disagree* with the plural subject?

So is my feeling for English going bad or if I did the right thing, how could I explain this to somebody who's learning English for instance?

Comment: It's not just time. Fifty to sixty miles **is** a long way to come. Fifty kilos **is** a lot to carry.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Years of experience that keeps us safe." vs "Years of experience that keep us safe."](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67503/years-of-experience-that-keeps-us-safe-vs-years-of-experience-that-keep-us-s). Except in that one you could make a case for singular **or** plural - but in this one there's no choice because ***a lot of time*** is singular, and the verb must agree with that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I have a doubt: Is it "Crosswords is a game" or "Crosswords are a game"?

Comment: @Shyam: I don't use the words *crossword* or *crosswords* this way. I would say "A crossword is a game" and "Crosswords are games".

Comment: @hippietrail,Shyam: I overstated my case. I don't have a problem with [crosswords are a good {singular noun phrase}](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22crosswords+are+a+good%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). I suspect most people wouldn't much like *any* variant of *"[a] crossword[s] is a game|are games"*. It's a gray area where there can't really be a "grammatical rule" because whatever the rule said, some people wouldn't like to apply it (in some contexts, at least).

Comment: @Fumble People doesn't like grammar.

Comment: @Shyam: There are other words in English which work this way: "Marbles is a game.", "Dominoes is a game.", "Dungeons and Dragons is a game.", etc.

Comment: @hippietrail: and to complicate things, consider "Marbles is a game where marbles are laid out in a circular area."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use **is** because you're talking about a single period of time with a range-based duration.

There are extensive discussions of the subtleties of [Collective Nouns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_noun) and [Mass Nouns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun) on Wikipedia that explain from a technical perspective why some seemingly plural things are treated as singular grammatically.

Comment: So this is one way in which a phrase can look plural but be grammatically singular?

Comment: @hippietrail - Absolutely.  It works too when the plural thing is a class of objects, i.e. when the subject is the class as a whole, not the individual instances within the class.

Comment: @Joel: I don't understand your comment. I don't think you'd say "trees is" under any circumstances, even if you're talking about trees as a class as a whole.

Comment: @PeterShor - Fair enough - I was referring specifically to _collective nouns_ and _mass nouns_.  For example you wouldn't say "the forest _are_ obscuring those trees" even though a forest is a collection of trees.  Similarly, for example, cutlery (collectively) _is_ made of metal.

Comment: I would really like to see an answer addressing this point from a technical view (grammatical or linguistic) before I accept one of the answers. I have a hunch we might be able to word some kind of "range-based duration" another way which might need **are**.

Comment: This has nothing to do with collective or mass nouns.  @hippietrail you should accept Peter Shor's answer.  Consider *five weeks is a long time to wait for a taxi.*  There is no collective noun in that sentence, just a single quantity of time whose duration happens to be something other than one unit.

Answer (score 5):

You use the singular because it's a quantity of time. From [this website](http://library.indstate.edu/writingcenter/esl/setvi/prints/SETVI3AP.html)

> Quantities or measurements of time, money, distance, weight usually take singular verbs.

It's not just restricted to time, money, distance and weight;

> Fifty milliamps is enough to kill a man.
>   Three G is enough to make a pilot black out.

Answer (score 0):

It should be **is** because you take the time collectively, so it's singular.

See 'Making Subjects and Verbs Agree', Item# 10 at 
http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/599/01/

Comment: Number 10 has nothing to do with the question; it's only talking about people. Further, it's inconsistent. If someone says "The crew *are* preparing to dock the ship," they will also say "My family *have* never been able to agree" (I believe these two sentences can have either a plural or a singular verb in American English).

Comment: @Peter Shor That is explained in the same place, as well.