# Verb agreement with nouns modified by numbers

Tags: nouns, numbers, verb-agreement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it “5-6 weeks are a lot of time” or “5-6 weeks is a lot of time”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67553/is-it-5-6-weeks-are-a-lot-of-time-or-5-6-weeks-is-a-lot-of-time)

I am writing about a baseball player who has 33 at-bats in his career.

Which is correct:

> Yes, 33 career at-bats qualifies/qualify as a small sample size.

My guess is that it should be qualify because at-bats is the subject, but it sounds odd.

Comment: The subject is *33 career at-bats* - which is plural, so *qualify* is the correct verb form. But people will often use singular *qualifies* in a context like this, where that number of "at-bats" is alternatively described as (singular) *"a small sample size"*.

Comment: A similar question: [_5 weeks is_ vs _5 weeks are_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67553/is-it-5-6-weeks-are-a-lot-of-time-or-5-6-weeks-is-a-lot-of-time)

Answer (score 1):

The argument could be made that there's an implicit 'having' in the sentence:

> Yes, [having] 33 career at-bats qualifies as a small sample size.

If you buy this argument, then the implicit 'having' is the gerund subject, and the verb for this gerund subject should be in singular form.

Answer (score -2):

qualifies.  the noun is "33 career at-bats" which is singular.

If the subject were "33 at-bats in one's career," it would be "qualify"