# Subject-verb agreement with implied subject

Tags: verb-agreement, collective-nouns, measuring-units

tl;dr Which is the appropriate verb in the following sentence?

> Apparently, 2,000 steps [is/are] hazardous to my sleep.

---

I use a sleep app that calculates a (dubious) sleep quality value and tracks that value against different daily metrics, one of which is steps taken.

[image: graph of steps taken vs sleep quality]

In the sentence I wrote above, should the verb be *is* or *are*?  It would be *is* if I rewrote it:

> Apparently, **taking** 2,000 steps is hazardous to my sleep.

or

> Apparently, **the taking of** 2,000 steps is hazardous to my sleep.

I *think* the preceding verb/verb-phrase is implied, but I'm unsure.

If it's not, there's another thing to consider.  Are the 2,000 steps taken as a whole or not?

It should be *are* if each individual step of those 2,000 is hazardous.

If they're a group of steps--as taking 1,000 or 3,000 steps evidently improves my sleep--I *think*, even though the group isn't explicitly stated, that it should still be *is*, but again, I am unsure.

What's the Stack Exchange consensus?

Also, I'm curious, if I did reword it to simply "taking 2,000 steps", what is the subject of the sentence?  "Me"?  i.e.

> Apparently, (me) taking 2,000 steps is hazardous to my health.

(I can make this a separate question if y'all think I should.)

Comment: For your bonus question, the subject of the sentence is the noun phrase *My taking 2000 steps,* very similar to *the taking of 2000 steps.*

Comment: Notice how [“Three strikes is all you get”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/67553) takes singular concord.

Comment: If you feel it answers your question, then sure.